# GNOME Always on top focus problem

Tags: gnome, bug-reporting

I'm Using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and when I'm setting a window to Always on Top and using another window that have another window, after closing sub window the focus returns to the always on top window. For Example:

1. Smplayer is always on top.
2. on Chromium click on `save page as`
3. close the save dialog
4. the focus must still be on the chromium but it's not. it's on the smplayer.

Is there anyway to fix this behavior?

*I also went to the gnome bugzilla to report it as a bug. but the classification is too much! I don't know what is the right place to report it.*

Comment: Always on top .. as in ALWAYS ?

Comment: @SorenA Unity doesn't have this problem. It shouldn't focus to the always on top window when we didn't select it. This Problem is getting more annoying when I'm setting SMPlayer to always on top for all workspaces and when I'm switching to another workspace, focused window isn't the window I selected last.